# Algorithm for allocating whole gold bars amongst thieves by % share of the booty

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, allocation

I have N big gold bars and 1 small gold bar equivalent in weight to some fraction x of a large bar. E.g N = 10 and x = 0.5 then I have 10.5 large bars worth of gold, in 10 large bars and 1 small bar

I want to distribute this between a gang of T thieves there thief i (T_i) has a share (s_i) of gold he or she should be entitled to. E.g. for T = 3 then Thief 1 has 40% share, Thief 2 has 50% share and Thief 3 has 10% share

What algorithm can I run to allocate the gold bars to the thieves so that the final share of the total gold (by weight) is closest to their desired shares? The gold bars cannot be cut or divided they must remain whole.

---

Example of how I thought about it, each thief gets NearestInteger((Tot Gold) * s_i) gold where Tot Gold = N + x = 10.5

Doing this approach with the numbers above

| Thief | share s_i | 10.5 * share | Rounded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40% | 4.2 | 4 |
| 2 | 50% | 5.25 | 5 |
| 3 | 10% | 1.05 | 1 |

There are several issues

- The total allocation is 4+5+1 = 10 not 10.5, since everyone's gold is rounded down. But it could also end up overshooting if everyone happens to get rounded up.
- This algorithm will never allocate the small fractional bar of gold since it works in whole numbers.
- I don't know if it's provably the closest final ratio

An extension would be to allocate Thief N - the final person any remainder of the gold, however this would bias them to always get the leftovers.

---

### Update: measuring best

To define what "best" is; I think one measure would be to find the algorithm which will minimise the pythagorean distance between the desired shares (s1,s2,...sn) and the result shares after running the algorithm (r1,r2,...rn). In case that several allocations are equally close (like 4 gold bars equally between 3 thieves, who gets the 4th one) then I don't care which one the algorithm goes with.

Comment: How do you want to measure the "closeness" of the final allocation?

Comment: @MattTimmermans Good question. I had not decided but maybe one good method would be to minimise the pythagorean distance between the desired shares `(s1,s2,...sn)` and the result shares after running the algorithm `(r1,r2,...rn)`. In case that several allocations are equally close (like 4 gold bars equally between 3 thieves, who gets the 4th one) then I don't care which one the algorithm goes with

Comment: @MattTimmermans Updated. Note I'm not wedded to that definition if it makes an algorithm harder. Something else sensible could work. But that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

A simple algorithm that works for your chosen metric is:

- Round everybody's target share down to an integral number of bars, and distribute those bars.  You'll be left with a residual target in [0,1) for each theif and some remaining bars.
- If you have M whole bars remaining, distribute them to the thieves with the highest residual targets, as long as those residuals are >= 0.5 bars.
- Give the fractional bar to the thief with next highest residual, as long as that residual >= 0.5x.

This will minimize the squared error, but it could leave some gold undistributed.

If you want to impose the additional restriction that all the gold has to be distributed, then you can do this:

- Round everybody's target share down to an integral number of bars, and distribute those bars.  You'll be left with a residual target in [0,1) for each theif and some remaining bars.
- If you have M whole bars remaining, distribute them to the thieves with the highest residual targets.
- Give the fractional bar to the thief with next highest residual.

If you want to prove that the allocation is optimal, it's not to hard to show that moving any of the whole bars to other thieves will produce a worse allocation.

Comment: Thanks the second algorithm sounds like a good first pass. I'm thinking about the situation that someone's residual happens to be "x" exactly, but they get allocated an additional whole bar from M rather than the perfect size small bar, because the other residuals are smaller. Seems a bit suboptimal but I think given my cost function of least squares then your algorithm is optimal over the whole population